# How to make a simple ajax call with Jquery and ASP .Net 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying the following:

```
$("#button_feedback").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: $('#button_feedback').data('url'),
        data: "{message: " + $('#feedback_content_wrapper textarea').val() + " }",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});

<input type="button" value="Enviar" class="button" id="button_feedback" data-url="@Url.Action("SendMail", "Contacto")"/>
```

And in my controller:

```
public class ContactoController : Controller
    {
        ...

        public ActionResult Send_Mail(string message)
        {
            return Json(new { mensaje = "Correo enviado con éxito" });
        }
}
```

However I keep getting:

POST http://localhost:11280/Contacto/SendMail404 Not Found

Why? Everything seems correct!!!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method name has an underscore. Either change your method name or modify the action in the UrlHelper to match with the underscore.

```
public ActionResult SendMail(string message) // note change from Send_Mail
{
    return Json(new { mensaje = "Correo enviado con éxito" });
}
```

Comment: how embarrassing..  I guess I'm too tired. Time to power off. Thank you hehehe =)

Answer (score 0):

After you fix the url issue, you'll want to change how you deal with the json in your callback.

You want to alert the mensaje property on your JSON result `alert (data.mensaje);`

Your current callback

```
success: function (data) {
   alert(data);
}
```

Will just show `[object Object]`

Comment: @content01 - sure - glad to help :)